# How to tokenize punctuations using the Tokenizer function tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tokenize

I use the `Tokenizer()` function from `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text` as :

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
s = ["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."]
t = Tokenizer()
t.fit_on_texts(s)
print(t.word_index)
```

Output :

```
{'the': 1, 'quick': 2, 'brown': 3, 'fox': 4, 'jumped': 5, 'over': 6, 'lazy': 7, 'dog': 8}
```

The Tokenizer function excludes the punctuation. How to tokenize the punctuation also? (`.`, in this example. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to separate the punctuations from the words with spaces. I do this with a preprocess function `pad_punctuation`. after this I apply `Tokenizer` with `filter=''`

```
import re
import string
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

def pad_punctuation(s): return re.sub(f"([{string.punctuation}])", r' \1 ', s)

S = ["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."]
S = [pad_punctuation(s) for s in S]

t = Tokenizer(filters='')
t.fit_on_texts(S)
print(t.word_index)
```

result:

```
{'the': 1, 'quick': 2, 'brown': 3, 'fox': 4, 'jumped': 5, 'over': 6, 'lazy': 7, 'dog': 8, '.': 9}
```

The `pad_punctuation` function is effective with all the punctuations